# Keeping a function executing under conditions

Tags: javascript

I got a problem in a game with javascript :

I've a pathfinding algorithm that hold in an array positions from the beginning point to the destination. One div have to follow that positions, and I've got an image associated to this div, which have to follow it. 
The problem is that the div is moving too fast for the image, so it's placing bad.

I'm searching for a method to say to this div that if the image is not arrived to that div position, so the div can't take immediately the next position, it have to wait.

I wrote this :

```
if (!(destX == player.x && destY == player.y)) {
        var path = grid.find(player.x / 40, player.y / 40, destX / 40, destY / 40);

        for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
            // If the image has arrived to the div position, function continue
            if (player.image.x == player.x && player.image.y == player.y) {
                player.x = path[i].position.x * 40; 
                player.y = path[i].position.y * 40;
            }
        }
    }
```

... but it's not working, because when the condition is not matching, the for loop goes to the next 'i' index...

Thanks for help !

EDIT : I would make some precisions, the function is inside a update loop :

```
Player.prototype.getMouseMove = function() {

$(".tile, .target").mouseup(function() {
    var destX = Math.round($(this).position().left);
    var destY = Math.round($(this).position().top);

    if (!(destX == player.x && destY == player.y)) {
        var path = grid.find(player.x / 40, player.y / 40, destX / 40, destY / 40);

        for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
            console.log(i); 
            if (player.image.x == player.x && player.image.y == player.y) {
                player.x = path[i].position.x * 40; 
                player.y = path[i].position.y * 40;
            }
            else i--;
        }
    }
});
```

}

Comment: What is the condition to identify If the image has arrived to the div position, is it `if (!(destX == player.x && destY == player.y))` ?

Comment: It's the second if condition : 'if (player.image.x == player.x && player.image.y == player.y)'      =>      "If the image position has arrived to the div position"

Answer (score 1):

Just modify it a bit

```
 for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
            // If the image has arrived to the div position, function continue
            if (player.image.x == player.x && player.image.y == player.y) {
                player.x = path[i].position.x * 40; 
                player.y = path[i].position.y * 40;
            }
            else i--; // It wont increase your i if condition is not satisfied.
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd just test it, and the game is crashing without error. For little moves one case to one case it's working but for the others the loop crash when i is egal to 2